# Google Analytics Admin API Final Release

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We need to migrate to the new Google Analytics Admin API, but this page indicates that it is currently an early preview version of the API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#ga4_properties_management

Is there an estimate for when a final version will be released?

Answer (score 0):

Conor,

The Google Analytics Admin API is likely a few weeks away from Beta release. It is not possible to give a reliable estimate regarding the availability of the final version of the API.

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: And here it is, 7 months later, same situation. Sigh.